# Not able to display Syncfusion Chart in UWP project

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp, syncfusion

I am using syncfusion charts in my project.There is no problem when i use it with droid project for xamarin but when I add a UWP project i am having issues.The project complies and gives the message "namespacename.exe exited with code 0" and the window closes.When I comment the Xaml code for syncfusion chart there is no issue.I have included the syncfusion dlls for uwp project in the uwp project and the main project.I am using Xamarin Forms 2.0 and using the version 14.2451.0.26. for syncfusion dll for chart
please find the code snippet :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:EWSMobile;assembly=EWSMobile" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:XLabs.Forms.Controls;assembly=XLabs.Forms" xmlns:EWSMobile="clr-namespace:EWSMobile;assembly=EWSMobile"
    xmlns:gauge="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.SfGauge.XForms;assembly=Syncfusion.SfGauge.XForms" xmlns:chart="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.SfChart.XForms;assembly=Syncfusion.SfChart.XForms" x:Class="EWSMobile.Dashboard" Title="Dashboard">

                ------------------
                ------------------
                ------------------
                            <chart:SfChart x:Name="ChartNews"   IsVisible="{Binding IsVisibleNews}" IsEnabled="false" HeightRequest="270" BackgroundColor="#2a334f"  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

                                                <chart:SfChart.Title>
                                                <chart:ChartTitle Text="News Analysis" TextColor="White" />
                                            </chart:SfChart.Title>
                                            <chart:SfChart.PrimaryAxis>
                                                <chart:CategoryAxis >

                                                ----------
                                                </chart:CategoryAxis>
                                            </chart:SfChart.PrimaryAxis>
                                            <chart:SfChart.SecondaryAxis>
                                                -------------
                                            </chart:SfChart.SecondaryAxis>
                                <chart:SfChart.Series>

                                    <chart:SplineSeries Label="Company"  XBindingPath="Week" ItemsSource="{Binding Date}" Color="#8a40af" />
                                </chart:SfChart.Series>
                            </chart:SfChart>

     -------------------


        </ContentPage.Content>
    </ContentPage>
```

Please find below message for the same:

> The thread 0x247c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>       'EWSUWP.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly'. 
>       The thread 0x2188 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>       The thread 0x1190 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>       The program '[2056] EWSUWP.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Comment: Use their support service.

Comment: it seems the application is crashing due to memory issues,need to either increase heap memory size or dellocate memory to resources(charts).

Answer (score 0):

Syncfusion 14.2* requires Xamarin.Forms 2.3 or higher.

You should also call `new SfChartRenderer();` code on your UWP project's `MainPage` constructor.

Comment: I upgraded the Xamarin Forms package to 2.3 and also added new SfChartRenderer(); to the main page constructor but still the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion: Create a POC with the desired component and see if the problem is still there. If yes, post your snippet to the SyncFusion support for better answers.